# Is there an escape character that does not match anything in Postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is there an escape character in Postgres that is "opposite" to `%`? When I use `where my_column like '%'` will return all the records. But is there an operator that does not match anything? As in `where my_column like MAGIC_OPERATOR` that will return none of the records? I am calling a stored procedure from the C# code and this is the situation that I am in:

My data:

```
GRADES_TABLE
--------------------------------------------------
          Math     |   History   |   English
Alice      A       |    NULL     |      B
Bob       NULL     |     A       |      B
Charlie    C       |     B       |     NULL
```

My function:

```
CREAT FUNCTION GetStudents(MathGrade CITEXT, HistGrade CITEXT, EngGrade CITEXT)
RETURNS TABLE (Student CITEXT)
AS $$
BEGIN
RETURN QUERY
    SELECT STUDENT FROM GRADES_TABLE WHERE 
        (COALESCE(Math, '') LIKE MathGrade
         OR COALESCE(History, '') LIKE HistGrade
         OR COALESCE(English, '') LIKE EngGrade
END $$
```

My C# code calling the stored procedure:

```
GetStudents("%", "%", "%") --> This should return Alice, Bob, and Charlie
GetStudents("A", "", "") --> This should return Alice
GetStudents("A", "A", "") --> This should return Alice and Bob
```

Since I have NULL values in the table so I have to use `COALESCE` to make them empty strings so they can be found by `like '%'`. But this way, all three calls in the C# code return Alice, Bob, and Charlie. It will be the same result if I pass in empty string like `GetStudents("A", "", "")`. So I am wondering if there is any special escape character that does not match anything? Obviously, I can pass in some garbage value `GetStudents("A", "IMPOSSIBLE_GRADES", "IMPOSSIBLE_GRADES")` and this will get me the desired result. But just wondering if there is any proper way to achieve this? Suggestions for making changes in the Postgres function or in the C# code are welcome as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
where my_column like null
```

In most cases, you could also use regular expressions:

```
where my_column ~ '^$'
```

Or:

```
where my_column like ''
```

The latter two only match empty strings.

Comment: The C# code will go through intermediate software so I have to pass in values with consistent datatypes. In this case, I can only pass in strings. But I have access to change either the C# code or the Postgres function. Or both if necessary.

Comment: Thanks! So this works but could you give an example of what would match `^$`? Since I have the ```COALESCE```, all the NULL values will be ```""```. Just want to make sure, so ```""``` is different from an "empty string", right?

Comment: @cxc . . . The empty string is `''` and it should be the only match to `'^$'`.

Comment: my mistake I meant ```''```. However, doesn't the ```COALESCE``` make all NULL values to ```''```? But I did try ```select  '^$' = '';``` and it returns false. Do you know why's that?

Comment: @csc . . . That should be a regular expression:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=760d8f4b5c119848e7571aeda937381b.

Comment: So if I pass in ```'^$'``` in C#, it will be ```...WHERE (COALESCE(Math, '') LIKE '^$' ``` in Postgres. Does it mean I'm comparing the column against the literal string ```'^$'``` instead of the regular expression? Since I have ```LIKE``` instead of ```~``` in my stored procedure?

Comment: @cxc . . . No, I messed up.  That is a regular expression.  For `LIKE` you just want the empty string `''`.  I already fixed the answer.

Comment: thanks for the update. But this way it wouldn't work, right? If I call ```GetStudents("A", "", "")``` in C#, the first parameter will find the students with an A in Math. But the second and third param will find the students with NULL values since I used ```(COALESCE(History, '')```. In this case I **only** want the students with an A in Math and no one else. I need this ```COALESCE``` in order to find these NULL values when I do a wild card search. So this is kinda the conundrum here.